# Performance hit after one week of up time - tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat, drools, activiti

My company uses Tomcat with spring,hibernate,cxf (for WS).
The product is a rule engine (holds rules, gets inputs and returns the output).
We use drools and activiti libraries to execute rules.
These webapp is being used by executing soap web services. Main 2 use cases are:
1) deploy new rule (some logic, drl files+xml)
2) execute existing rule with a given input

Our client does 1+2 repetitively during one week (with high loads, batch executions). After one week, the execution time becomes x20 slower (something that took 0.5 seconds take 10 seconds). We used JvisulVm to profile the app,
didn't see hint for the cause (there is not too much cpu usage or memory usage).
After a restart this the execution becomes fast again (this hapeens on multiple servers which are virtual - so it's not hardware related). Any ideas?

Comment: It reminds me of a system that is pushed into trashing - too many processes at OS level. Ties in with the app being well-behaved. But surely you monitored the system to see how many processes etc.?

Comment: You must have a memory leak somewhere in your application!  You should be taking memory snapshot from your frech run and your one week instance and compare them! There must be a lot of referenced (even though not any more used) objects.

Comment: are you using caches in your application ?

Comment: @laune Yes, othe tomcat instances on same machine are responding well

Comment: @YounesRegaieg How do I compare memory snapshots?Yes we are using ehcache in our application, but it has some limits (entry count)

Comment: @volatile: sometimes when you are using caches and your caches sizes are not adapted to your requirements / application design / data scale, you risk spending way more time on adding elements to the cache/ taking elements out of the cache than doing the actual required job !

Comment: @volatile: I guess jvisual vm offer the possibility of taking a snapshot / loading a snap shot / comparing snapshots, otherwise I would advise you to consider some alternative profiling tool such as jprofiler

Comment: How is use case 1 handled? Terminate the session and create a new one? Release resources? - You speak of "deploy new rule", "execute existing rule" - always singular? That true?

Comment: @laune Of course we support multiple sessions. We use syncronization when needed. Execution and deployment of the same rule mutually exclude each other (we have locking mechanism that checks it). While profiling with jvisualVM I didn't see any deadlocks. After execution we don't release all resources... because we may need to execute same rule again... we have cache with size limit, cache eviction is  done by LRU (and by cache size limit)

Comment: I suggest you give it another 24 hrs here, then pose the Q at the Drools usage list. You might want to describe the Drools part in more detail, how you create and dispose stateful (or -less?) sessions, how many rules in the RB, making sure to clean out all the facts,... and the Drools version. BTW, did you run the Drools part as a local app, mimicking multiple sessions and all? Should do, before you put it on a server.

Comment: @laune thanks, good ideas.